# Mounted VHD gives access denied during file copy

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, robocopy, vhd

I want to copy files from VM to another. I'm running windows 2008 on the VM Manager. Both machines are Server 2012. I tuned them both off. Mounted the VHDs to the manger pc. I can see the both files and folders, but cannot copy.

I want to move files from Windows/WinSxS to the other machine Winsxs.

```
robocopy I:\Windows\WinSxs K:\Windows\WinSxs
```

After that it loops on access denied, waiting 30 seconds.

Why am I getting access denied. I'm using a domain admin account and administrator power shell.

Comment: Why are you copying stuff from WinSXS?

Comment: Now that is quite the story. in a nutshell, I'm attempting to get my fully updated server core to install the gui. The fact that it is updated seems to be the root issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give permission to this folder and the sub-folders to copy files from this folder. If the destination folder is also a machines working folder then you have to give permission to that folder too. Read http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-need-to-copy-some-files-into-the-winsys-folder/8f6c3a6f-3483-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?auth=1 , this will surely help